# Is $x^2-y$ squarefree?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x^2>y$ and $x \equiv2$  mod $4$. $ $ 
Is it true that $x^2-y$ is squarefree? 
How can I prove or disprove this?

Comment: Are there any constraints on $y$, like at least that it has to be positive?

Answer (score 3):

Use some small example, like $x=6=4+2$, $y=27$. Then $x^2=36>27=y$, and $x^2-y=9=3^2$, which is a square.

Answer (score 1):

$y$ can be *anything* less than $x^2$?

Then let $y = x^2 - $ something *not* square-free.

Example:  Let $x = 6\equiv 2 \mod 4$.  $x^2 = 36$.  The numbers $4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,9,18,27,25$ are all not square-free.  Let $y$ be $36$ minus *any* of those.  So $y = 36-12 = 24$.

Then $x^2 - y= 36-24 = 12 = 3*4$ is not square free.

Comment: I suspect there is something *vital* omitted from the question.